# Expected Outcome of a LVDS Transmitter Output if there's no Termination Resistor

Tags: resistors, clock, termination, lvds

I know this sounds like a silly question, but what would the expected waveform of a LVDS transmitter that has no termination resistor look like? If the expected output were to be a 20 MHz LVDS clock and I were to probe it with a single ended scope, would I be able to see something that resembles a 20 MHz LVDS clock?

Background:
I have a test board that has an oscillator that outputs a 20 MHz LVDS clock. We intentionally did not put a termination resistor across because when the test board interfaces with another board, the clock will go to a receiver that has internal termination. We left an unpopulated resistor on the LVDS clock in case we wanted to measure it without the main board as an option. But in the hopes of speeding up testing the test board, I was wondering if I could get away with measuring the clock without the resistor and at least verifying the output is at least 20 MHz.

If anyone has any images of what the LVDS line would look like on a scope, I would appreciate an example!

Thanks!

Comment: LVDS is a current drive interface, where the drivers source & sink 3.5 mA.  So the answer to your questions come down to how a particular driver behaves when driving an open circuit.  My guess is that the outputs would swing from close to VCC to GND, but I have no experience to back that up.

Comment: The waveform would depend on the cable length and impedance. E.g. if you have a cable longer than lambda/10, which would be few meters length, you would see signal reflections from the unterminated cable end. But in every case you should be able to see some 20 MHz base clock.

Comment: It might help if you mentioned which LVDS oscillator you have, to read what the data sheet says about the output interface.

Comment: Just probe it with the scope in 50 ohm (terminated) mode (use a BNC cable, not a probe)?